# How can I join two dataframes based on the same date?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Im trying to get the values of 'temp' from df2 to df1 based on the same date. You notice that they dont have the same length and that im trying to get the temperature of that date into df1.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.to_datetime(['2018-01', '2018-01', '2018-01',
                            '2018-01', '2018-01', '2018-02',
                            '2018-02', '2018-02', '2018-03']),
    'station': [50,31,47,10,51,23,24,26,22],
    'sales': [3000, 2000, 1800, 1700, 1500, 1600,900,500,300]})

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.to_datetime(['2018-01', '2018-02', '2018-03']),
    'temp': [45, 55, 70]})
```

The resulting dataframe i would like would be:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'date': pd.to_datetime(['2018-01', '2018-01', '2018-01',
                                '2018-01', '2018-01', '2018-02',
                                '2018-02', '2018-02', '2018-03']),
        'station': [50,31,47,10,51,23,24,26,22],
        'sales': [3000, 2000, 1800, 1700, 1500, 1600,900,500,300],
        'temp': [45,45,45,45,45,55,55,55,70})
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is left join - you want each row from df1 to have the temperature from df2 - df1 is the "left" dataframe, and df2 is the "right" dataframe - you can do it with "merge" command in pandas:

```
 result_df = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='date')
```